# I want to change the color of svg while it is in outer file and imported with img tag

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I use google fonts and icons, and save them into themes folder, I know that SVG files can be imported with the img tag, but on my website, I have a setting which the user can change the theme, for example, light and dark, my problem is everything color's changes but not the SVGs that imported with `<img>`, is there a way to change the color of SVG file if it was imported using `<img>`?? if not, is there a way to change the `fill` attribute from the SVG file on import??

Comment: What do you mean by "on import"?

Comment: I mean I want to edit the fill attribute when I get the svg file into html file

Comment: https://iconmeister.github.io ``<svg-icon>`` gives you full control over SVG icons with attributes, properties and CSS variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct that you can't change an SVG's `fill` attribute via CSS if you use it in the `src` of an `img` tag – you need to have the contents of the SVG in your document.

You could try using CSS `filter` to change the appearance of the image though, in particular the `brightness` or `invert` options:

```
<img src="myimage.svg" class="invert">

<style>
.grayscale { filter: grayscale(100%); }
.contrast { filter: contrast(160%); }
.brightness { filter: brightness(0.25); }
.invert { filter: invert(100%); }
</style>
```

Comment: thanks `invent` class really worked and it is switching between white and black, what I wanted is to at least switch the colors and this solution really worked